# shell script when set e and o not run right

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

the bellow code, when e and o set sample time,then the last line not run, why?

```
set -x
set -e
set -o pipefail

add=$(echo 'x' |grep '1x' | wc -l)
echo $add
echo '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than mixing single letter options and `-o option`, use long option names for everything, then it will be clearer:

```
set -o xtrace -o errexit -o pipefail
```

Where `-o xtrace` is `-x`, `-o errexit` is `-e` (`pipefail`, from ksh and now found in most other shells, and soon to be standard has no single letter equivalent in most shells)

`errexit` means that if a non-handled command fails, the script exits. `pipefail` means that if a pipeline has any component that fails, the whole pipeline is considered failed (otherwise only the rightmost component is considered).

So that `echo 'x' |grep '1x' | wc -l` pipeline fails if either of those 3 commands (`echo`, `grep` and `wc`) fails.

Here, `grep` won't be able to find a line that contains `1x` in the output of `echo`, so will report failure. Because of `errexit`, that will exit the subshell that runs in `$(...)` with the same failure exit status. As a result the `var=$(...)` assignment will also result in failure, and the shell running the script will also exit.

Note that `grep | wc -l` is better written `grep -c`.

If you want to avoid the effect of `errexit`, you can handle the error.

That could be:

```
var=$(echo x | grep -c 1x || : no match should not be a fatal error)
```

Here because there's `|| another command` after the pipeline, the failures are considered by the shell to be manually handled, so `errexit` doesn't apply. The command here is `:` which does nothing successfully (like `true` except it accepts arguments which it doesn't do anything with).

Here it's the pipeline error that is being handled. You could also handle the error for `grep` alone:

```
var=$(
  echo x | {
    grep 1x || : no match should not be a fatal error
  } | wc -l
)
```

Allowing failures of `echo` or `wc` if any to exit that script (note that involves an extra subshell to run that `grep || :`).

Or handle the assignment failure:

```
var=$(echo x | grep -c 1x) || : no match should not be a fatal error
```

Note that whether that disables `errexit` inside the subshell depends on the shell and version thereof. For instance, some shells will output `x`, some others an empty line in `sh -ec 'v=$(false; echo x) || true; echo "$v"'`.

`errexit` (aka `set -e`) is a very brittle feature. I wouldn't recommend using it for anything but the simplest scripts and do error handling manually instead. You should ask yourself what should happen if a command fails for each line of your script, same as you'd do in any programming language.

Comment: got it, thank you very much